# LoginManager TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask-login

## Problem

I can't use LoginManager in Flask. If I set `login_view` It returns `'NoneType' object is not callable`.
My Files are:

```
Main Folder>  
    > main.py
    > website >
          > __init__.py
          > views.py
          > models.py
          > static
          > templates
```

In My `__init__.py`

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_login import LoginManager
from .views import views
from .models import db,User
from flask_mobility import Mobility
from os import path

DB_NAME="database.db"

def create_app():
    app=Flask(__name__)
    Mobility(app)
    
    loginmanager=LoginManager(app)
    loginmanager.login_view('auth.login')

    app.config['SECRET_KEY']='no nothing nobody'
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']=f'sqlite:///{DB_NAME}'
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS']=False
    db.init_app(app)
    app.register_blueprint(views, url_prefix='/')
    create_database(app)
    return app

def create_database(app):
    if not path.exists('website/'+DB_NAME):
        db.create_all(app=app)
```

In my `main.py`

```
from website import create_app

app=create_app()

if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=80,debug=True)
```

## The Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\Python Projects\flask\main.py", line 4, in <module>
    app=create_app()
  File "G:\Python Projects\flask\website\__init__.py", line 14, in create_app
    loginmanager.login_view('auth.login')
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
[Finished in 2.9s]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see that there is no `auth` module in your project. But, you are calling `login` function from `auth`.

If you're a beginner, `login_view` is the view of the login page of your project. If user is not logged in, then flask tries to redirect the user to that view. So, If your project already has a login page, replace `auth.login` with the module and function name of your login view.

Comment: Thanks  you. I watched a video on youtube. and just copy pasted the `auth.login`. Now I replaced that with my login url `/login` and It's Now Working

Comment: @Shahriar Glad it helped! Generally, it's a good practice to use function name of login view instead of route. So, you don't have to change the URL in two places incase if you update it.